# inverse hyperbolic sine (asinh) from other trigonometric functions (for use in Presto SQL)

Tags: trigonometry

I need to use the inverse hyperbolic function (asinh) in Presto SQL, but the only available trigonometric functions are:
acos, asin, atan, cos, cosh, sin, tan, tanh

Is there some equality function that will enable me to "create" the asinh function?
E.g. if I needed tan(x) but only had sin(x) and cos(x), I could have easily used sin(x)/cos(x). Is there a similar workaround I can use in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. It turns out that, for any real number $x$,$$\operatorname{asinh}(x)=\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right).$$